# Sage Pay REST API

Tags: rest, opayo

We are using the REST api integration with our own form and we have disabled  TLS 1.0 on our site.   However we are still getting the occasional user getting back a C002 Network  error when attempting to submit the card identifier to your api.   I’ve run both the sites through this SSL checker and both sites have the  exact same protocols enabled/disabled.
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=connect.msv.com&hideResults=on   https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pi-live.sagepay.com&hideResults=on

I would have expected if the client can access our site, they will be able to  access your site? As we have the same protocols disabled?   Is there anything else we can look it to diagnose this problem?  here are certain situations (which our not in our control, as it’s the customer’s browsers) where they cannot connect to the gateway.  One example of this situation is using a browser that doesn’t support TSL 1.1 or higher.

I am aware of this requirement.

We have TSL 1.0 disabled on our site, so customers who have TSL 1.0 won’t even be able to load our page.  What is happening is customers are loading our page, so they have TSL 1.1 or 1.2 enabled, but they are then getting back the same error message as shown in the screenshot.  So you have another restriction on the gateway site, that is stopping some customers connecting.

I am just trying to find out what that restriction is, so I can place that on our site as well.